# translate.instant sometimes returns key instead of value and sometimes returns a wrong value of the previous language selected

Tags: angular

I use angular 7.

my Application currently supports 2 languages, arabic and English. arabic is default language.

Users are able to switch language using dropdown list with this code :

**flags-menu-public.component.html :**

```
<a
class="nav-link dropdown-toggle"
id="dropdown-flag"
href="javascript:void(0);"
data-toggle="dropdown"
aria-haspopup="true"
aria-expanded="false"
>

<span [ngClass]="currentLang"></span>

</a
>



<div 
class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right"
aria-labelledby="dropdown-flag"
>
<a
  class="dropdown-item"
  href="javascript:void(0);"
  data-language="en" (click)="changeLanguage('en')"
  ><i class="flag-icon flag-icon-us" ></i> English</a
><a
  class="dropdown-item"
  href="javascript:void(0);"
  data-language="en" (click)="changeLanguage('ar')"
  ><i class="flag-icon flag-icon-sa" ></i> Arabic</a
>
</div>
```

**flags-menu-public.component.ts :**

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewEncapsulation } from '@angular/core';
import { BootstrapConfigService } from 'app/bootstrap-config.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-flags-menu-public',
  templateUrl: './flags-menu-public.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./flags-menu-public.component.scss'],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
export class FlagsMenuPublicComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private boot: BootstrapConfigService)
   {
     this.currentLang = 'flag-icon flag-icon-sa';
    
    }
  public currentLang: any = 'flag-icon flag-icon-ar';

  ngOnInit() {
    if(this.boot.getCurrentLang() == 'ar') {
      this.currentLang = 'flag-icon flag-icon-sa'
    }
    if(this.boot.getCurrentLang() == 'en') {
      this.currentLang = 'flag-icon flag-icon-us'
    }
   
  }

  changeLanguage(lang) {
   
    if(lang == 'ar') {
      this.currentLang = 'flag-icon flag-icon-sa'
    }
    if(lang == 'en') {
      this.currentLang = 'flag-icon flag-icon-gb'
    }
   
    this.boot.setCurrentLang(lang);
  }

}
```

**BootstrapConfigService :**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { CookieService } from 'ngx-cookie';
import { Observable, of ,  Subject } from 'rxjs';
import { Renderer2, RendererFactory2 } from '@angular/core';
import { Router} from '@angular/router';
import { TranslateService } from '@ngx-translate/core';
import { JhiLanguageService } from 'ng-jhipster';
import {Location} from "@angular/common";

@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class BootstrapConfigService {

  public langs: string[] = [];
  public currentLang: string=null;
  private currentLangChangedSource = new Subject<string>();
  private currentLangChangedSource$ = this.currentLangChangedSource.asObservable();
  renderer: Renderer2 = null;

  constructor(private cookieService: CookieService,
    private translate: TranslateService,
    private languageService: JhiLanguageService,
    private rootRenderer: RendererFactory2, private router: Router,  private location: Location ) {
    this.renderer = rootRenderer.createRenderer(document.querySelector('html'), null);
  }

  public boot(): Observable<boolean> {
 
    this.currentLang = this.checkEmptyValue(this.cookieService.get('be_lang')) ? 'ar' : this.cookieService.get('be_lang');


   this.cookieService.put('be_lang', this.currentLang);

    this.translate.use(this.currentLang);
    this.languageService.changeLanguage(this.currentLang);
    
    this.renderer.setAttribute(
      document.querySelector('html'),
      'dir',
      this.currentLang === 'ar' ? 'rtl' : 'ltr'
    );

    
    return of(true);
  }

  public doAfterCurrentLangChanged(next: (value: string) => void) {
    return this.currentLangChangedSource$.subscribe(next);
  }

  public setCurrentLang(lang: string) {
    this.cookieService.put('be_lang', lang);
    this.currentLang = lang;
    this.currentLangChangedSource.next(lang);
    this.translate.use(lang);
    this.languageService.changeLanguage(lang);
    this.updatePageDirection(lang);
  }

  public getCurrentLang() {
    return this.cookieService.get('be_lang');
  }

  public updatePageDirection(lang: string) {
    this.renderer.setAttribute(
        document.querySelector('html'),
        'dir',
        lang === 'ar' ? 'rtl' : 'ltr'
    );
 

    this.router.navigate([this.location.path()]);
    location.reload();
  }


  checkEmptyValue(stringValue:any): boolean {
    if (typeof stringValue != 'undefined' && stringValue) {
      return false;
    }
    return true;
  }

}
```

my probleme is that after call `location.reload();`
`translate.instant` sometimes returns key instead of value

also sometimes it return a wrong value of the previous language selected .

for example the current hmtl page is **rtl** and the value returned with `translate.instant` is for english translated which is in **enappservice.json.** and not get the correct value in **arappservice.json.**

**app.module.ts**

```
import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser';
import {BrowserAnimationsModule} from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import {NgModule, Injector,LOCALE_ID, Injectable,APP_INITIALIZER } from '@angular/core';

import {AgmCoreModule} from '@agm/core';
import {routing} from './app.routing';
import {AppSettings} from './app.settings';
import {AppComponent} from './app.component';
import {Ng2Webstorage, LocalStorageService, SessionStorageService} from 'ngx-webstorage';
import {JhiEventManager} from 'ng-jhipster';
import {JhipsterCoreModule} from '../app/core';
import {HttpHandler, HttpInterceptor, HttpRequest, HTTP_INTERCEPTORS} from '@angular/common/http';
import {AuthInterceptor} from './blocks/interceptor/auth.interceptor';
import {AuthExpiredInterceptor} from './blocks/interceptor/auth-expired.interceptor';
import {ErrorHandlerInterceptor} from './blocks/interceptor/errorhandler.interceptor';
import {NotificationInterceptor} from './blocks/interceptor/notification.interceptor';
import {TranslateModule, TranslateLoader,TranslateService} from '@ngx-translate/core';
import {HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http';
import {TranslateHttpLoader} from '@ngx-translate/http-loader';
import {HttpClientModule} from '@angular/common/http';
import {CookieModule} from 'ngx-cookie';
import {NotFoundComponent} from "app/pages/errors/not-found/not-found.component";
import { ModalModule } from 'ngx-bootstrap/modal';
import {CalendarModule} from "angular-calendar";
import { NgxExtendedPdfViewerModule } from 'ngx-extended-pdf-viewer';
import { NgIdleKeepaliveModule } from '@ng-idle/keepalive';


import { LOCATION_INITIALIZED, registerLocaleData } from '@angular/common';
import localeAr from '@angular/common/locales/ar';
import localeArExtra from '@angular/common/locales/extra/ar';
registerLocaleData(localeAr, 'ar', localeArExtra);


export function createTranslateLoader(http: HttpClient) {
  return new TranslateHttpLoader(http, './assets/i18n/', 'appservice.json?_=1008360857952');
}


@Injectable()
export class NoCacheHeadersInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
    intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler) {
        const authReq = req.clone({
            setHeaders: {
                'Cache-Control': 'no-cache',
                 Pragma: 'no-cache'
            }
        });
        return next.handle(authReq);    
    }
}

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    NotFoundComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    CookieModule.forRoot(),
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    NgIdleKeepaliveModule.forRoot(),

    AgmCoreModule.forRoot({
      apiKey: 'AIzaSyBNcjxo_35'
    }),
    routing,
    Ng2Webstorage.forRoot({prefix: 'jhi', separator: '-'}),
    JhipsterCoreModule,   
    TranslateModule.forRoot({
      loader: {
        provide: TranslateLoader,
        useFactory: createTranslateLoader,
        deps: [HttpClient],
      },
    }),

    ModalModule.forRoot(),
    CalendarModule.forRoot(),
    NgxExtendedPdfViewerModule

  ],
  providers: [
    { provide: LOCALE_ID, useValue: 'ar-AR' },
    {
      provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
      useClass: AuthInterceptor,
      multi: true,
      deps: [LocalStorageService, SessionStorageService]
    },
    {
      provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
      useClass: AuthExpiredInterceptor,
      multi: true,
      deps: [Injector]
    },
    {
      provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
      useClass: ErrorHandlerInterceptor,
      multi: true,
      deps: [JhiEventManager]
    },
    {
      provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
      useClass: NotificationInterceptor,
      multi: true,
      deps: [Injector]
    },
    {
      provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
      useClass: NoCacheHeadersInterceptor,
      multi: true
    },

    AppSettings

  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]


})
export class AppModule {
}
```

**my html component contain**

```
<div >
  <div class="content-overlay"></div>

  <div class="content-wrapper">
    <div class="content-header">
      <div class="content-header-left col-md-9 col-12">
        <div class="row breadcrumbs-top">
          <div class="col-12 p-0">
            <h2 class="content-header-title float-right mb-0 active" >
             
              {{ translate.instant('taysirApp.library.publicDetail')}}
           
            
            </h2>

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="content-body">
      <div class="page-header">
        <br>
        <br>
        <div class="row align-items-center m-0">
    
    {{ translate.instant('myApp.main.publicDetailTitle')}}
        
    <br>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row flex-wrap align-items-stretch">
        <div class="col-12 col-md-12">
          <div class="card pt-1">
            <div class="display-details">
            
            
              <div class="display-info-box is-hovered">
                <div class="row align-items-center">
                  <div class="col col-5">
                    <p class="display-item">
                      {{ translate.instant('myApp.main.publicGridBook')}}
                    </p>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col col-7">
                    <p class="display-item is-bold">{{this.itemDetail.bookName}}</p>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              
                
           
              <div class="display-info-box is-hovered">
                <div class="row align-items-center">
                  <div class="col col-5">
                    <p class="display-item">
                      {{ translate.instant('myApp.main.publicGridAuthor')}}
                    </p>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col col-7">
                    <p class="display-item is-bold">{{this.itemDetail.authorName}}</p>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
             
            
            
              
              
              
              


               

              
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        
        
        
    
      </div>
      
        <br>
        
    
      

      


      
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**and my ts component contain :**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {TranslateService} from '@ngx-translate/core';
import { Title } from '@angular/platform-browser';



@Component({
  selector: 'app-search-book',
  templateUrl: './search-book.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./search-book.component.scss']
})
export class SearchBookComponent implements OnInit {


  constructor( public translate: TranslateService,private titleService:Title) 
    
    {

     }
    


  ngOnInit() {

    this.titleService.setTitle(
      this.translate.instant('myApp.main.publicSearchTitle')
      );

   

  }

}
```

can someone help me to get all time the correct value of `translate.instant` related to the language selected